# Responsive font is not working

Tags: css, fonts, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive font I use [fittext.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js/blob/master/jquery.fittext.js) library, But I face a problem in specifying the default font-size.

The plugin allow me to enter the min and max width of the font size, The problem that the header takes the minimum size as the default size and don't change!!

here's my code

```
 <div class="notes">
         <h1>Large Title</h1>
         <p>Text about image 1 in slider it may have many many many text</p>
</div>
```

and here's css

```
.notes{
position: absolute;
top:30.9%;
left:5.06%;
width:27.9%;
min-height:234px;
height:auto;
color:#ffffff;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #eb7b7a;
}
div.notes h1{

padding-left: 45px;
width:100%;
float: right;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 6em ;
position: relative;
margin-top:54px;


}
```

and I put the script tag after  tag

```
$(".notes h1").fitText(1, { minFontSize: '60px', maxFontSize: '105px' });
```

The default size is 60 and still 60 when resizing the window!

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you make the header bigger? Looks like the font-size should increase to take up the available space.

You might get more answers if you show your working code...

Answer (score 0):

> CSS Tips
>
> Make sure your headline is display: block; or display: inline-block; with a specified width, i.e. width: 100%.

Don't see display: block or display: inline-block in your CSS. Make sure to follow their readme!

https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Comment: h1 and div by default are block elements!

Comment: So why does the tutorial tell you to add this anyway? Surely with them writing this script and all, they'd be aware that h1 and div are block elements?

Comment: Anyway I add them, but nothing change!